# "The notion of a", "The notion of the", or "The notion of"

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm going to do a conference about, let's say, radishes. In this conference, I'll let the attendees question over whether radishes exist or not.

Which title should my conference have between those 3, and why?

- The notion of the radish is misleading
- The notion of a radish is misleading
- The notion of radish is misleading

Comment: I’d go with “radishes”, but of your choices, “the radish”. I can’t think of how to explain why the others feel wrong.

Comment: It's hard to know what your conference is trying to establish - whether radishes exist, whether they are not what they seem, whether they have been wrongly described or classified! My query is not about grammar. I'm just puzzled.

Comment: A title is not usually a full sentence. So, none of them works.

Comment: Were I to see any of those titles, it would seem to me to suggest that radishes were themselves having notions - a bizarre thought, but then the conference may have been oriented to science fiction. But let's move on from radishes and suppose its about a subject like homeopathy - which to some is real, but to the others is codswallop. I think I'd go with something like "Homeopathy, real or imagined?" The question of which, if any article to use, seems quite peripheral. Any of them would work.

Comment: They are all fine. It all depends on context.

Comment: Can you use the real situation instead of a strange made up situation.  You aren't really going to be talking about the existence of radishes.  If I knew what you were really asking about it would be possible to give a better answer.  Radishes aren't "notions" so the whole situation is unnatural.

Comment: None of them sound right: you might use "notion" if you meant "people's ideas of/about radishes", but that's not what you mean. As James K says, it's very hard to judge whether a silly made up example is idiomatic. (You might say "people's notion of gender" if you were going to argue gender doesn't exist, but that's because people have notions of gender in a way they don't have notions of radishes, and there's no issue about singular/plural/articles there. And "the notion of God" would be possible, but there plural has a different meaning re monotheism/polytheism.)

Comment: I agree with Stuart and James above.  None of these are clear, because of semantic mismatch.  You might instead speak of "The notion of the existence of a radish" or "The notion that the radish exists" instead.   If you use a determiner p.p. after "notion", it must specify *a type of notion*, and not *a type of vegetable*.

Answer (score -1):

"If what has been talked about is a single radish, then use 'radish'." I think that's wrong. A single item uses the singular article. Using no article at all makes it clear that the discussion cannot be limited to any particular radish.

Comment: This should be a comment under the answer it addresses, not an answer.